# minikube/kubectl, not running locally in Win10-pro-64-bit-laptop

Tags: windows, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

GitHub issue link :

https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/1994

Docker on Windows installed already, docker is running fine and the containers are running fine.

Docker stopped and made running as well , for running K8s setup. Both scenarios, same status- minikube did not start.

I installed Google Cloud SDK and then started minikube/kubectl for setting K8S, FYI.
Hyper-V was running all along these setup, in my laptop.

Trying to run K8S locally on my laptop using {kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/minikube/} and observed the issues below.

```
Started kubectl cluster-info.
```

C:>kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://192.168.99.100:8443

and then exited after sometime.

```
minikube version command was run.
Output is as follows :
```

C:>minikube-windows-amd64 version
minikube version: v0.21.0

```
minikube start command was run.
Output is as follows :
```

C:>minikube-windows-amd64 start
Starting local Kubernetes v1.7.0 cluster...
Starting VM...
E0921 18:52:12.921824 10592 start.go:129] Error starting host: Error starting stopped host: Unable to start the VM: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe startvm minikube --type headless failed:
VBoxManage.exe: error: VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole

Details: 00:00:01.552591 Power up failed (vrc=VERR_VMX_NO_VMX, rc=E_FAIL (0X80004005)).

Retrying.
E0921 18:52:12.924743 10592 start.go:135] Error starting host: Error starting stopped host: Unable to start the VM: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe startvm minikube --type headless failed:
VBoxManage.exe: error: VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole

Details: 00:00:01.552591 Power up failed (vrc=VERR_VMX_NO_VMX, rc=E_FAIL (0X80004005))

I then ran kubectl cluster-info dump. Output is as follows :

C:>kubectl cluster-info dump
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Then, I ran status of minikube. Output is as follows :

C:>minikube-windows-amd64 status
minikube: Saved
localkube:
kubectl:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minikube on Windows uses VirtualBox per default and fails to create your virtual machine because Hyper-V [disables VT-x access for other hypervisors](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/118561b9-7155-46e3-a874-6a38b35c67fd/hyperv-disables-vtx-for-other-hypervisors?forum=w8itprogeneral). You need to either [configure minikube to use Hyper-V](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wasimbloch/2017/01/23/setting-up-kubernetes-on-windows10-laptop-with-minikube/) or disable Hyper-V and run `minikube start` again.